# Is it possible to characterize all finite groups $G$ whose coprime graph contains precisely three or precisely four leaves?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

Is it possible to characterize all finite groups $G$ whose
coprime graph contains precisely three or precisely four leaves?

In section 3 of *X. Ma, H. Wei, and L. Yang, The coprime graph of a group, Int. J. Group Theory, 3 No. 3
(2014) 1323*, Ma et al characterized the groups
whose coprime graphs have exactly 0, 1, or 2 leaves. However, they do not go further than that.

The degree of a vertex in a graph is the number of vertices in the graph that are adjacent to it. A vertex that has degree one is called a 'leaf'.

Comment: I find it strange that you define the degree of a vertex in a graph, and a leaf in a graph (both of which I knew already), but you do not define the coprime graph of a finite group, which I have heard of, but would still prefer to be reminded of the definition.